# Correct way of managing threads

Tags: c#, multithreading, sockets

I'm building a C# Socket Server. My code currently works but I am not sure if this is the correct way to do it.

When a `TcpClient` is connected I put it in a new object with the following Methods, I then call `Init()` to start checking if data is available, when data is available I call an event that I listen on to start reading the buffer using methods I created like `ReadInt32(), ReadByte(), ReadString() ReadObject<T>()`

```
    public void Init()
    {
        ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(Read);
    }

    private void Read(object state)
    {
        if (IsClientConnected())
        {
            if (_connected.Available > 0)
            {
                OnDataAvailable(_connected.Available);
            }
            Init();
        }
    }
```

Should I use a `While` loop here or should I restart the `Init()` like I am currently doing? Then should I use a `BackgroundWorker`, `Thread`, or `Task` instead of `ThreadPool`?

I also was thinking of changing `Init()` to `BeginWait(some sort of callback here)` and removing the `Init()` inside the `Read()` and then just call `BeginWait` again where needed

My purpose is to listen to commands and reply on commands. With an x number of clients connected at the same time.

So the scenario is as follow:

I have an application that connects to the server.
The server then Initializes a new object with TcpClient as a parameter in the constructor. The server then adds the connected client to a room with another client. This room listens on each of the client's events `DataAvailable` look at following

```
    private void Client_DataAvailable(ClientWrapper sender, int data)
    {
        var command = (Commands)Client.ReadByte();
        switch (command)
        {
            case Commands.RequestConnectId: // 1

                var buffer = new WriteBuffer(Commands.RequestConnectId);
                buffer.WriteInt32(sender.ConnectId);
                sender.Reply(buffer);

                break;
            case Commands.WriteText: //2

                var buffer = new WriteBuffer(Commands.WriteText);
                buffer.WriteString(sender.ReadString());
                BroadCast(sender.ConnectId,buffer);//Send to the other client

                break;
        }
    }
```

Comment: The correct way to handle threads in C#5 is to NOT THREAD AT ALL FOR I/O. Instead you use `async` and `await` for your asynchronicity.

Comment: Any suggestions how I can make this to apply `async` `await`
I am editing my question with more information of what I am doing

Comment: Your question has exceeded the scope of what is an acceptable question in StackOverflow. Unfortunately I am not able to advise you which SE network is better suited for this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct way to read a socket is to just read from it. The call will not complete until data is ready. There is no need for events. The `Available` property almost always is a bug so don't use that.

Just execute:

```
var command = (Commands)Client.ReadByte();
```

immediately. It is fine to run that on a background thread (as opposed to what was suggested in the comments). Threads become a problem once you have too many of them. If you maintain a few dozen socket connections only there is no issue with that.

You also could use async IO preferably with `await`. The same idea applies: Just read.

If you want to process a stream of command simply wrap this in a loop:

```
while (true) {
 ReadCommand();
 WriteResponse();
}
```